# Recyclerview Endless scroll reloads page onscroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and i'm trying to implement Endless Scroll with this [popular android Endless scroll Library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView). It almost working well, except that when i get to the buttom of the current list, it reloads and starts from the top instead of continuing from the last visible item.

This is my Scroll Listerner.

```
scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(manager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
            // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
            loadMore(page);
            ++page;
        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

This is my loadMore()

```
public void loadMore(int page) {

    String url = myurl + page;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Log.i("Responses", response);
            ArrayList<Deal> deals = new JsonConverter<Deal>().toArrayList(response, Deal.class);
            dealArrayList.addAll(deals);
            adapter = new DealAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dealArrayList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            newList = deals;
            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(newList.size(), dealArrayList.size());
            stopAnim();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad Network Connection. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopAnim();

        }
    }
    );

    int socketTimeout = 30000; // 30 seconds. You can change it
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);


}
```

I can't figure out whats wrong. 
Help.

Edited..
My app calls this function when it first lunches and then call the loadMore function when i scroll.

```
public void firstRun(int page) {

    String url = myurl + page;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("Responses", response);
            dealArrayList = new JsonConverter<Deal>().toArrayList(response, Deal.class);
            adapter = new DealAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dealArrayList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            newList = dealArrayList;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            stopAnim();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad Network Connection. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopAnim();

        }
    }
    );

    int socketTimeout = 30000; // 30 seconds. You can change it
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);


}
```

This is my Adapter

```
public class DealAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DealAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Deal> deals;

public DealAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Deal> deals) {
    this.context = context;
    this.deals = deals;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);


    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Deal deal = deals.get(position);
    holder.mCardTitle.setText(deal.title);
    holder.mCardLocation.setText(deal.location);
    holder.mCardDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(deal.discount));
    holder.mCardPrice.setText(deal.price);
    holder.mCardContact.setText(deal.contact);
    holder.mCardDescription.setText(deal.description);
    String url = myurl + deal.image;
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url).resize(0,300)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.load)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .into(holder.mCardImage);


    holder.mCardDescription.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isClicked = false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isClicked){
                //This will shrink textview to 2 lines if it is expanded.
                holder.mCardDescription.setMaxLines(2);
                holder.more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mCardInvisible.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isClicked = false;
            } else {
                //This will expand the textview if it is of 2 lines
                holder.mCardDescription.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                holder.more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mCardInvisible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isClicked = true;
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (deals != null) {
        return deals.size();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mCardTitle;
    private ImageView mCardImage;
    private TextView mCardLocation;
    private TextView mCardDescription;
    private TextView mCardContact;
    private TextView mCardPrice;
    private TextView mCardDiscount, more;
    private LinearLayout mCardInvisible;

    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mCardTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardTitle);
        mCardImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardImage);
        mCardLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardLocation);
        mCardDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardDescription);
        mCardContact = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardContact);
        mCardPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardPrice);
        mCardDiscount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardDiscount);
        more = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardMore);
        mCardInvisible = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCardInvisible);

    }


}
```

}

Edited:: This is my OnRefresh Listener

```
mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    firstRun(1);
                }
            }, 3000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: you are setting `adapter = new DealAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dealArrayList);` everytime you reach the bottom, you have to initialize your adapter once then just add the extra items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I moved that line of code to the onCreate function but its still the same

Comment: `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` must be set also once

Comment: i just tried that.. when i set 'mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);' outside the loadmore function, nothing gets loaded in my app

Comment: please show the adapter code

Comment: I just added my adapter code. and also the function the my app calls when it first run before calling the loadMore when i scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter add a new function that merges the data you have with the new ones:

```
public void addAll(List data){
    deals.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Your onResponse in loadMore function should look like:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
    //Log.i("Responses", response);
    ArrayList<Deal> deals = new JsonConverter<Deal>().toArrayList(response, Deal.class);
    adapter.addAll(deals);
    stopAnim();
}
```

Comment: it worked.. thanks very much.. One tiny problem. When i refresh the activity, onScroll doesn't load anymore. Onrefresh, i call the firstRun function

Comment: @MaxBillionaire update your code with what you have now and also the Onrefresh code

Comment: i just added my OnRefresh code.. should i update the adapter,loadMore etc..

Comment: you need to add a new function in your adapter public void clearAll() {
        deals.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

then call it on onRefresh, also reset the page variable

Comment: great.. it worked. thanks very much. you just saved my day

Comment: @MaxBillionaire no problem

Comment: Now i have to show the progress bar at the bottom when loading more items. i guess i need to ask that as a separate question